# Fetching user permission using Google Cloud API

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I need to check does the user credentials have access to a project and do have following permissions like.

```
compute.images.get,
compute.images.list,
compute.instanceGroups.get,
compute.instances.start,
compute.instances.delete,
compute.instanceTemplates.list
```

I am using following PHP google cloud library

```
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client
```

Fetching resource manager object, I am trying to execute testIamPermissions method for a project.

```
https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/testIamPermissions
```

It is working fine using API endpoint but using PHP SDK there is no method available for it only **folders** and **operation** object is available.

I am using the following JSON file

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "p123",
  "private_key_id": "p123",
  "private_key": "p123",
  "client_email": "test@p123.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": 12345",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/p123.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look to this documentation related to the [projects.testIamPermissions](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/testIamPermissions) and see the PHP example included in the documentation reference.